# Drawing a branched diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows

Here is the figure I want to draw:

> [image]

Any guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site, which is why yours was downvoted. For future reference, we prefer that you post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @Teepeemm Ok. I promise I will do that next time. Thanks for clarifying this rule to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tikz-cd` is a nice package to draw diagrams, the syntax is easy to understand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    & A\ar{rd}{j_1}\\
    B\ar{ru}{i_1} \ar{r}{i_2}\ar{rd}[swap]{i_3} & C\ar{r}{j_2} & D\\
    & E\ar{ru}[swap]{j_3}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have used the correct code of @Luis Turcio adapting it with the syntax of `xy` package with the same tips of the `tikz-cd`.

It is very closer with this last package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\xymatrix{%
    & A\ar[rd]^{j_1}\\
    B\ar[ru]^{i_1} \ar[r]^{i_2}\ar[rd]_{i_3} & C\ar[r]^{j_2} & D\\
    & E\ar[ru]_{j_3}
    }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]